# SQL Subtruct Quantity from the MAX Calculated Value Row with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

please help to resolve this,

I am trying to figure out how to update Table2 using QtyToSubtract and Product_ID from Table1, recalculating CurrentQty and Balance every time Row is updated.

For each ROW in Table1 I need to update Current Qty and Balance in Table2 
subtracting from CurrentQty using the Row with MAX BALANCE for that PRODUCT_ID.
It means same record can be updated several times if after Subtracting it holds Max BALANCE still.

Table1  holds qty to subtract:

```
 PRODUCT_ID         QTYtoSubtract
  11111111               2
  11111111               2
  11111111               2
  22222222               6
  22222222               6
```

Table2 needs to be updated

```
PRODUCT_ID     OriginalQTY    CurrentQty      BALANCE  = Initial+ Current           
 11111111             46              12            58
 11111111             15              40            55
 22222222              6               1             7
 22222222             24               6            28
 22222222             15               8            23
```

RESULT should be like this :

```
 PRODUCT_ID     OriginalQTY    CurrentQty      BALANCE  = Initial+ Current           
 11111111           46              8            54
 11111111           15             38            53
 22222222            6              1             7
 22222222           24              0            22
 22222222           15              2            17
```

Comment: How do you know the order of the rows on Table1?, for what you want it seems that you'll need to subtract those values in order

Comment: Hello, order in the Table1 is not important. It holds the minimum Set Quantity that needs to be subtracted several times, each time from the max balance Row in table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is one of those rare times where a `CURSOR` seems to be the best choice:

```
DECLARE @Product_ID VARCHAR(8), @Qty INT

DECLARE CC CURSOR 
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY [PRODUCT_ID], [QTYtoSubtract] DESC

OPEN CC
FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @Product_ID, @Qty
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  *,
                RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Balance DESC)
        FROM Table2
        WHERE PRODUCT_ID = @Product_ID
    )
    UPDATE CTE
    SET BALANCE = BALANCE - @Qty
    WHERE RN = 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @Product_ID, @Qty
END
CLOSE CC
DEALLOCATE CC

SELECT *
FROM Table2
```

Results:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ PRODUCT_ID ║ OriginalQTY ║ CurrentQty ║ BALANCE ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║   11111111 ║          46 ║         12 ║      54 ║
║   11111111 ║          15 ║         40 ║      53 ║
║   22222222 ║           6 ║          1 ║       7 ║
║   22222222 ║          24 ║          6 ║      22 ║
║   22222222 ║          15 ║          8 ║      17 ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

And [**here is a demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/190e5/1) of this.

Comment: thank you! I did not want to believe that cursor is my only choice, suffered for several days, trying to find set-based solution :) thank you for your answer.